# set default value of an ENV variable in Dockerfile

Tags: java, docker

I have a custom base image where I have set some environment variable during the build, this way:

**Dockerfile of the base image**

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
...
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-8
...
```

Then I use this docker image as a base image of another images.
In the child images I use these pre-configured variables and everything works fine.

But the code quality checker rightfully complains about missing declaration in the child images and shows warnings. That warnings are correct, because the code quality checker does not see that this variables are defined in the parent image.

**Dockerfile of the child image:**

```
FROM my-base-image:1.0.0
...
RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ...
```

Is there any nice way to assign default value to a variable IN the `Dockerfile` during the image build if it is not set (in the parent image)?

I am looking for something similar than bash has: `JAVA_HOME="${1:-$DEFAULT_VALUE}"`.

Like this, which of course, does not work in `Dockerfile`: `ENV JAVA_HOME="${this:-"default-value"}"`

I know that I can use `*.env` file and set default values there, and I can also define default values in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

But my question is not related to this.
My question is related to the use case, where the `ENV`, e.g `ENV JAVA_HOME="..."` is defined in the parent image.

Comment: Hi. What if change code to 

`#dockerfile 1
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk-8`

`#dockerfile 2
ARG var=$JAVA_HOME
RUN $var/bin/java ...`
Maybe in this case quality checker will not be so picky?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. In this case checker complains about missing variable on the line of the `ARG`.